# When are interface builder IBOutlet objects created

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder, uilabel

I am using the iPad master / detail project template and I'm trying to update some `UILabels` in the `detailViewController` when the app is first run.

Here is My Code :

```
 (void)setObject:(id)newObject
{
    if (_object != newObject) {
        [_object release];
        _object = [newObject retain];

        [self configureView];
    }

    if (self.masterPopoverController != nil) {
        [self.masterPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)configureView
{
    [self updateDetails];
}

- (void) updateDetails
{
    NSLog(@"Details = %@", self.details);
    NSLog (@"detailLabel %@", self.detailLabel);
    self.detailLabel.text = [self.details objectForKey:@"aKey"];
}
- (IBAction)refresh:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    [self updateDetails];
}
```

`setEvent` is called from the Master View Controller's `viewDidLoad` method as selecting it's tableview's 1st row as a default.

```
if (![self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow])
{
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:0];
    [self.detailViewController setObject:[self.sortedObjects objectAtIndex:0]];
}
```

When I run the code the `detailLabel` is not changed and the `NSLog` says `self.detailLabel` is (null). If 'refresh' is called later from a button click `detailLabel` is not null and updates correctly. How can I do this to make sure the `detailLabel` has been created and is not (null)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IBOutlet objects will be created at the time of viewDidLoad() of that object(detail view, but not master view).

call the `[self updateDetails];` in viewdidLoad() method of detail view controller to avoid this problem.

Comment: Was trying to avoid it as it's uncertain whether self.details is will be empty when viewDidLoad od detail view controller is called. self.sortedObjects is populated from URL on another thread and setObject is called when it's done. I think the best way is to call updateDetails from multiple places and check for self.detailLabel being (null).